# Using breakpoints from OllyDbg in Windbg

Tags: ollydbg, windbg

I found a breakpoint in OllyDbg that works for my purposes. But now I want to use WinDbg for scripting and when I try to set the same breakpoint, I get no breaks.

In OllyDbg, the following breakpoint gets me exactly what I want:

`Address=75B0C4FA |  Module=KERNELBA | Active=Always | Disassembly=CMP EAX,103`

But when I try to set a breakpoint in WinDbg , it never comes back with anything:

`bp 75b0c4fa`

According to [the MS Dev Center documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538903(v=vs.85).aspx) for the `bp` command, I should be able to reference addresses specifically, but in my searching, most people are using `bp` to reference API calls, such as `bp ReadFile` (which does break as expected).

My questions: is it possible to use the breakpoint (75B0C4FA) using WinDbg?
And if so, what am I missing in terms of adapting the address I have to make it work in Windbg? 
Does it have to do with `bp ReadFile` accessing the ReadFile API calls for the main process, while with my breakpoint, it is trying to put breaks into sub module?

Comment: It might also be a parse error if you don't use the "0x" prefix for addresses. But as others mentioned it's probably ASLR biting you in the ass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dlls do not load at same address the load address is randomised due to aslr subtract the base address of kernelbase from your address in ollydbg viz75xxxx - say 74xxxxx. = 01xxxxx. Now in windbg find where kernelbase is loaded. Ssy 58xxxxxx. Add the 01xxxxx to this base address. And  set bp viz 58xxxxx + 01xxxxx = 59xxxxx

Bp 59xxxxxx.

Read about rva aslr loadaddress etc to get a hang of this

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I looked up what you were talking about here with the randomized address space. One thing I don't understand is this "viz" when I googled for it, it was mostly other responses from you on stack overflow, etc... Can you explain that? Thank you!

Comment: Viz is an adverb a contraction of videlecit a latin word that means namely/ for example  look it up on wikipedia.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viz.       The abbreviation viz. (or viz without a full stop), short for the Latin videlicet, is used as a synonym for "namely", "that is to say", "to wit", or "as follows". It is typically used to introduce examples or further details to illustrate a point.[1]